# How many external style-sheets are required for cross browser compatibility?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have just started web development after a few years. Mostly in the past I would specify a style-sheet dedicated to IE6. Now, Chrome and Safari seem to be rendering elements better, over FireFox.

What is standard procedure for external style-sheets these days? IE6 (STILL?) - IE8? FF even?

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone has advice specifically catered to marketplace development, ie XHTML / Wordpress development.

Comment: I think the accurate answer is none, because non-styled pages work in all browsers ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specified number of stylesheets. Usually it is one for **IE** and one for rest of the browsers. Note that there exist solutions such as [ie7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) or [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/) to make IE behave like standard-compliant browser.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use 2 stylesheets. One core one, and one for IE6.

Most of the modern browsers simply ignore anything that they don't support, and dont have quite the sheer number of behaviours that require hacks.

Answer (score 1):

Given that a stylesheet isn't *required* at all, the answer is none. I would still say you need only 1 though. (If you've created your css properly and used a proper doctype). Technically you shouldn't need to have browser specific styles at all. And for the few times you might, you *can* use Star Hacks for IE...

Answer (score 1):

I think question you're asking relates back to the much bigger topic of how *best* to handle cross-browser issues.

It's a wide and varied topic, but to help you with you're specific question about CSS branching (forking)... you may be interested in the following article from "A List Apart"

"Stop Forking with CSS3" http://www.alistapart.com/articles/stop-forking-with-css3/

Cheers.